# Using an 'entity type number' within the record ID to identify the Entity

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm working with an off-the-shelf application at my company and there is an interesting database feature (one of many) which the vendors have implemented.  I haven't seen it used in production before and I'm hoping to get some more information on it.

Each database table refers to a particular entity type.  For example, `TBL_Person`, `TBL_Organisation`, `TBL_Address`.  The IDs however, for each table, always start with the same group of digits, e.g. all `TBL_Address` records begin with `1401`, all `TBL_Person` records begin with `1500`.  The unique part is then appended after that.

Advantages from what I can see are, sheerly from a development point of view, are as follows:

- It's an *enormous* database (about 600 tables, many with over 150 columns).  So if while scanning the table I find columns such as `WId`, `RId`, `LId`, or `UnhelpfullyNamed_Id`, I know instantly what it's referring to (thanks to a little program they have also provided where you type the first four digits and it tells you what the entity is and what table to find it in)
- They store different variations of entities in the same table - e.g. a `TBL_Vehicle` record might be a Car (1234), Truck (2345), Motorbike (3456), so you don't need to use inheritance etc unless it's truly necessary

Disadvantages (in a general sense if this was used elsewhere) might be:

- Encourages laziness with table design - redundant columns if storing many entity types in the same table
- Adds confusion for a developer looking at it who is not aware of this

Is there a term for this design pattern/feature?  Are there any other well known databases which implement this?  Are there any other dis/advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By merging two pieces of information into the single field, this "design" violates the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore the first normal form.

Logically, the same could have been achieved by having a composite primary key `{type, id}`. I'm guessing that the decision to "merge" type and id was driven by their application design and a desire to have "simple" keys.

Answer (score 1):

In examples like this, there is often **NO** database design in the first place.
Everything is designed and implemented on the application level (may be OO) and things are then stored (persisted) somewhere -- in this case in a database. Database is simply a "storage under application".

In cases where database design is applied, a data-centric model is used. Once finished, the database can "stand on its own" -- does not need the application to make sense out of data.

There may or may not be an ORM mapper involved, so when it comes to those large tables you may be looking to a result of a *single-table inheritance* implemented by the mapper.